# Double line rule in memoir header

Tags: header-footer, memoir, rules

I need like this

header

____________________________________ (this smaller height)
____________________________________ (this bigger height)

I guess i need to redefine this from memoir class:

```
\newcommand{\makeheadrule}[3]{%
  \mem@ps@safe@change{#1}%
  \@namedef{#1headrule}{%
    \hrule\@width #2\@height #3 \vskip-#3}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\pagestyle{ruled}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine `\ruledheadrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ruledheadrule}{%
  \hrule \@width \textwidth \@height \normalrulethickness
  \vskip \normalrulethickness
  \hrule \@width \textwidth \@height 2\normalrulethickness
  \vskip -4\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter name}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Above I redefined `\ruledheadrule` to insert the regular-width rule, followed by a regular-width space, followed by a double-width rule. You can change these parameters to suit your needs.

Comment: what last line(\vskip -4\normalrulethickness) do? changed '4' by other numer and has no effect..commented it and same..no effect

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili: The rules are inserted vertically and together with the positive `\vskip`s actually enlarge the header. The negative `\vskip` at the end is to remove this additional height that has been inserted so the rules don't take up an vertical height in the overall header height. As I've inserted vertical content totalling `4\normalrulethickness` (1 rule @ `\normalrulethickness`, 1 skip @ `\normalrulethickness` and 1 rule @ `2\normalrulethickness`), this is corrected by a negative `-4\normalrulethickness` vertical skip.

Comment: ok..i got it..but why i dont see effect of changing negative vskips? ok i have some \vspace* commands in preamble scripts... Thank you very much..